# Ruby on Rails - Path variable without using resources route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hyperlink, path, routes

I have a controller, let's just call it FruitsController, that grabs all of the fruit and sends it to the index view.  In the view, I want to show links to the individual pages for those fruits.  I'm using the format:

```
<% @fruits.each do |fruit| %>
    <%= link_to fruit.name, fruit_path(fruit) %>       
<% end %>
```

And this works great when I have the route `resources :fruits`, but I don't want routes for deleting, saving, and updating, so I don't want to use `resources`.  But when I just do individual routes for showing all and individual fruits, I get the error *fruit_path function is not defined*, and when I use the function `fruits_path` it works but it just appends a period to the path like */fruits.1*.  How can I use the fruit_path function without using resources?  Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a number of ways you could do this; in your `config/routes.rb`, any of the following should work:

```
resources :fruits, only: :show

resources :fruits, except: [:index, :edit, :destroy, :update] # etc

get 'fruits/:id', to: 'fruits#show', as: :fruit

scope controller: :fruits do
    get 'fruits/:id' => :show, as: :fruit
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You're not limited to just resources, you can customize and create your own routes, for example:

get '/:username/photos', to: 'users#show', as: 'collage'
  
 to: means controller/action, in this case users is the controller and show is the action.
  
 as: creates a path for you 'collage_path'

you can find good info regarding routing =>http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html